# Problem with power config (powercfg) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate as a developer box. 
When it starts, if I don't run any program, browser or app, it goes to sleep without any problem, but, when I start working on it, there's a moment when it starts getting awake forever.
Even the monitor is on forever, it is never turned off. However, the sleep button works immediately.

I tried then

> powercfg /energy

and I got this message

> The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded.

I searched for that dll and found it in **C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-energyefficiencywizard_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_74c5223f50a58045** folder.

I tried also

> powercfg /requests

and got this weird result

> DISPLAY:
>   None.
>   
>   SYSTEM:
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   [DRIVER] ?
>   
>   AWAYMODE:
>   None.

I couldn't determine yet the culprit of this, I had a similar problem with chrome some time ago but when I closed Chrome everything came back to normal, now it's not the case.

I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials as Antivirus and it's updated regularly by the way.

I can't find anything related on the internet, at least in Spanish or English which are the languages I can read.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the command prompt as administrator and run `powercfg` in that window.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, even when running as Administrator.  There must be another cause.